# Group by two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a table as below that I want to create cohort months by group by date_contact and user_id. I received error message saying that "cohort_month" is not a valid name.
[image]

```
SELECT user_id, CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
from cohort
group by user_id, cohort_month
```

Any suggestions please? thanks!

Comment: Can you please share expected output. Which columns you want along with sample output data ( especially when userid or cohort_month is repeating).

Comment: For group by you have to use the actual expression, the alias won't work yet - only works in order by. It has to do with the order of processing in the SQL select statement.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the aliases from the `select` clause in the `group by` clause.
There are two ways of solving this - Either repeat the expression in the `group by` clause or use a derived table (or cte):

```
SELECT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
FROM cohort
GROUP BY user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120)
```

Or

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
    FROM cohort

)

SELECT user_id, cohort_month
FROM CTE
GROUP BY user_id, cohort_month
```

However, in this particular case you don't need `group by` at all, you can simply use `distinct`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
FROM cohort
```

And a side note: I've changed your `varchar(7)` to `char(7)` - don't use varchar if you know the length is fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried `SELECT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
from cohort
group by CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120)` but sql server still doesn't let me use group by on `CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120)`

Comment: because you've specified `user_id` in the `select` clause but not in the `group by` clause....

Comment: If I used `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
FROM cohort`, sql server says that I cannot select cohort.user_id because it is not included in GROUP BY

Comment: Thanks. even I included user_id in group by clause still received error

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. the `distinct` query should not have a `group by` clause.

Comment: I didn't add group by in the `distinct` query. The code I used is same as the codes you typed `SELECT DISTINCT user_id, CONVERT(CHAR(7), min(date_contact), 120) AS cohort_month
FROM cohort
`

Comment: The distinct query does not have a group by, so it's highly unlikely SQL Server will complain about a column that's not in the group by clause...